# How to increase the distance of an axis title from the plot when using non-default axis positions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to increase the spacing between the facet strips and the axis titles.

I have a plot using `facet_grid` with axis titles in non-default positions: top and right.

The `margin` argument of `axis.title` has no impact at all: `theme(axis.title = element_text(margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20)))` does nothing. 
I've tried suppressing `axis.tick` and `axis.text` through `scale` instead of `theme`, but it makes no difference.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
example.data <- data.frame(x.var = rep(-2:2, 5),
                           y.var = rep(-2:2, each=5),
                           boolean.var = as.logical(sample(1:1000, 25) %% 2))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
example.data %>% ggplot(aes(fill = boolean.var)) +
    geom_rect(xmin = -1, xmax = 1, ymin = -1, ymax = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "(X Title)", position = "top", limits = c(-0.5,0.5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "(Y Title)", position = "right", limits = c(-0.5,0.5)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
    facet_grid(y.var ~ x.var) +
    theme(panel.margin=unit(0.25 , "lines"),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 24, margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20)),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_text(margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20)))
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you must use the arguments `axis.title.x.top` and `axis.title.y.right`.

Individually specifying `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y`, which works when the axis titles are in the default (down, left) positions, still doesn't work.

Here is the full example, with correct spacing:

```
example.data <- data.frame(x.var = rep(-2:2, 5),
                           y.var = rep(-2:2, each=5),
                           boolean.var = as.logical(sample(1:1000, 25) %% 2))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
example.data %>% ggplot(aes(fill = boolean.var)) +
    geom_rect(xmin = -1, xmax = 1, ymin = -1, ymax = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "(X Title)", position = "top", limits = c(-0.5,0.5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "(Y Title)", position = "right", limits = c(-0.5,0.5)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
    facet_grid(y.var ~ x.var) +
    theme(panel.margin=unit(0.25 , "lines"),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 24, margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20)),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(1, 0, 15, 0)),
          axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 15)))
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]